# asignar valores para que las funciones hagan su trabajo

Tags: javascript

Lo que necesito es sencillo. En varias funciones puse los datos para recopilarlos mas adelante. En la funcion puntuacion() declare condicionales en el cual si es par 3 y tira 3 tiros el resultado es par.
El resultado que obtengo solo es "Jose Amieva hizo un Hoyo en 1". Como le hago para darle valores en el cual Jose Amieva hizo 4 tiros en un par 5? Asi el resultado saldra "Jose Amieva hizo un Birdie"

```
function parFunc(input){
  var par;
  if(input == 3){
    par = 3; 
  } else if (input == 4){
    par = 4;
  } else if (input == 5){
    par = 5;
  } else {
    par = "xxx";
  }
  return par;
}


function tirosFunc(input){
  var tiros;

if(input == 1){
    tiros = 1;
  } else if (input == 2){
    tiros = 2;
  } else if (input == 3){
    tiros = 3;
  } else if (input == 4){
    tiros = 4;
  } else if (input == 5){
    tiros = 5;
  } else if (input == 6){
    tiros = 6;
  } else if ( input == 7){
    tiros == 7;
  } else {
    tiros == "xxx";
  }
  return tiros;
}


var Puntuacion =  {
    holeInOne: "Hoyo en 1",
    albatros: "Albatros",
    aguila: "Aguila",
    birdie: "Birdie",
    par: "Par",
    bogey: "Bogey",
    dobleBogey: "Doble Bogey"
  };

function puntuacion(){
  var punt;
  if(parFunc(3) && tirosFunc(1)){
    punt = Puntuacion.holeInOne; 
  } else if (parFunc(3) && tirosFunc(2)){
    punt = Puntuacion.birdie;
  } else if (parFunc(3) && tirosFunc(3)){
    punt = Puntuacion.par;
  } else if (parFunc(3) && tirosFunc(4)){
    punt = Puntuacion.bogey;
  } else if (parFunc(3) && tirosFunc(5)){
    punt = Puntuacion.dobleBogey;
  }
  return punt;
}

function Persona(nombre, apellido){

    return {
      nombre: nombre,
      apellido: apellido
    };
}

var JugadorJose = Persona("Jose", "Amieva");

function asignacion(input){
    return JugadorJose.nombre + " " + JugadorJose.apellido + " hizo un " + puntuacion();
}
console.log(asignacion(1));
```

Comment: Por favor, échale un vistazo a [ask] y explica mejor el problema

Comment: En qué momento de la función asignación utilizas el parámetro de entrada input. No estás enlazando este dato por ningún lado, según se ve aquí, por lo que la función puntuación no va a funcionar correctamente. Otra cosa sería que input fuera una variable global, pero en ese caso no haría falta pasarla por parámetro.

Comment: ¿Te has fijado que `puntuacion()` no tiene parámetros de entrada? ¿Cómo calculas la puntuación si no entregas nada de lo que obtener el número de intentos que realizó? ¿Has pensado en almacenar esa información en una clase propia o en la misma que `Persona`?